# Finding $b$ and $d$ such that $2x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d $ has roots $x=\sqrt2-3$ and $x=3i+2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> I've got the following function:
> $$f(x)=2x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$$
> Given the two roots $x=(\sqrt2-3)$ and $x=(3i+2)$, I need to compute values $b$ and $d$.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of how to start this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Just to clarify, that's the information I've got. No more, no less.

Comment: Is any information given about $a,b,c,d$?

Comment: If $(a,b,c,d)$ are real numbers, you know three roots.

Comment: Complex roots always come in conjugate pairs so you know that $x=(-3i+2)$ is also a root.

Comment: If $a,b,c,d$ are given to be rationals, you know all the roots. Then you can easily find $b$ and $d$. Otherwise, given information is insufficient.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I understand that if $(2+3i)$ is a root, then $(2-3i)$ should also be a root, which means I know three of them. But how do I get the fourth one?

Comment: @takuma-san do you know the final answer of the question like are you having the answer key of this question?

Comment: Are you double sure you weren't told that the coefficients are integer ? Please reproduce the question verbatim.

Answer (score 4):

This is a basic application of [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas). Here is one way we can approach the problem:

Assuming rational coefficients, there are two conjugate pairs we are dealing with, namely:

- the surd conjugate pair: $\left(\sqrt 2-3\right)$ and $\left(-\sqrt 2 - 3\right)$, whose sum is $-6$ and product is $7$
- the complex conjugate pair: $(3i+2)$ and $(-3i+2)$, whose sum is $4$ and product is $13$

Using the sum and product of roots, a quadratic function that has the surd conjugate pair as zeros must thus have the form $A_1(x^2+6x+7)$; a quadratic function that has the complex conjugate pair as zeros must have the form $A_2(x^2-4x+13)$, where $A_1,A_2\in\mathbb Q$.

We can now think of the original quartic $f(x)$ as a product of two quadratic functions with these respective forms:

$$2x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=A_1A_2\left(x^4+2x^3-4x^2+50x+91\right)$$

Noticing from the coefficient of $x^4$ that this can only hold if $A_1A_2=2$, we have:

$$2x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=2x^4+4x^3-8x^2+100x+182$$

From there, we can just compare coefficients to get the values of $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me immensely! I was (and still am) confused about the surd conjugate pair, but this definitely clarified the scope of what needs to be done!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Regarding the surd conjugate pair, if the coefficients of the polynomial are rational (which is not explicitly stated in the original problem) then something like $\sqrt2$ behaves similarly to $i$ in that if $a+b\sqrt2$ is a zero then $a-b\sqrt2$ is also a zero. After all, $i$ is also the square root of an integer.